# Microsoft Excel on Mac unintentionally clears my cells

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, office-for-mac

When I navigate through cells using the arrow keys I have encountered some annoying behavior. If I stop at some cell for a second or so, it automatically enters edit mode for that cell clearing anything that was in it, which in worst case causes me to lose data if I don't discover it right away. Is there to disable this?

I haven't seen this problem in the Windows version.

Comment: Which versions of OS X and Excel? Do you have any extra software installed that modifies keyboard or mouse behavior?

Comment: I am currently running Lion and Excel is version 14.1.4. Regarding the extra software I have *USB Overdrive* installed, but that is only for mouse settings.